# Spectral Networks and Deep Locally Connected Networks on Graphs

Tags: graph-neural-networks

I’m reading the paper [Spectral Networks and Deep Locally Connected Networks on Graphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6203) and I’m having a hard time understanding the notation shown in the picture below (the scribbles are mine):
[image]

Specifically, I don’t understand the notation for the matrix F. Why does it include an i and a j?